# Google Colab PDB debugger hides the typed command

Tags: debugging, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory, pdb

I use google colab and try to set a breakpoint using pdb.set_trace(), but when I type the command the characters are hidden. Something like "*********" appears behind the'>pdb' command when I type the commands as shown in the picture below. I try with the stty sane and reset command in the cells, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the same problem now and I don't know how to solve it. Thanks!